# Django Rest Framework update don't save changes

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models related through a one to one field, and I want to create a `REST` services that manages them both as they where one. The `post` works perfectly so far, and new instances are created in both models as they where one, but the `put` method just does nothing. It raises no error or anything, it just leaves the data unchanged.

These are my models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    legal_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()
    address = models.TextField(max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}]{}".format(self.id, self.name)

class Hotel(models.Model):
    company = models.OneToOneField('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='city_hotels')
    category = models.ForeignKey('HotelCategory', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='category_hotels')
    capacity = models.IntegerField()
    position = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    in_pickup = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company.name
```

This is my ViewSet:

```
class HotelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Hotel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.HotelSerializer
```

These are my serializers:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Company
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'legal_name', 'url', 'address')

class HotelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = models.Hotel
        fields = ('company', 'code', 'city', 'category', 'capacity', 'position', 'in_pickup')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        company_data = validated_data.pop('company')
        new_company=models.Company.objects.create(**company_data)
        hotel = models.Hotel.objects.create(company=new_company, **validated_data)

        return hotel

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        company = models.Company(
            id=instance.company.id,
            name=instance.company.name,
            legal_name=instance.company.legal_name,
            url=instance.company.url,
            address=instance.company.address
        )

        company.save()
        instance.save()

       return instance
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that `instance` carries the original data, and `validated_data` carries the new data. I was saving the original data back.

I had to replace `instance` data with `validated_data` data and then save `instance`:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):

    company_data = validated_data.pop('company')
    company = models.Company.objects.get(id=instance.company.id)
    company.name = company_data.get('name')
    company.legal_name = company_data.get('legal_name')
    company.tax_id = company_data.get('tax_id')
    company.url = company_data.get('url')
    company.address = company_data.get('address')

    instance.company = company
    instance.code = validated_data.get('code', instance.code)
    instance.city = validated_data.get('city', instance.city)
    instance.category = validated_data.get('category', instance.category)
    instance.capacity = validated_data.get('capacity', instance.capacity)
    instance.position = validated_data.get('position', instance.position)
    instance.in_pickup = validated_data.get('in_pickup', instance.in_pickup)
    instance.is_active = validated_data.get('is_active', instance.is_active)

    company.save()
    instance.save()

    return instance
```

`put` method works handsomely now.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of company instead of updating the one that belongs to the Hotel instance.

```
company = Company.objects.get(id=instance.company.id)
company.name = instance.company.name
company.legal_name = instance.company.name
company.url = instance.company.url
company.address = instance.company.address
company.save()
instance.save()
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The data still remain unchanged after the `put`